# How do I restore an Outlook mailbox to an Active Directory user that was deleted and then successfully restored?

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, outlook-2016

everyone. Sorry if this is difficult to understand, but I accidentally deleted a user profile/account in Active Directory (AD) in Windows Server 2012 R2. I successfully restored the user profile/account to its original state, which was confirmed by the user (They were able to access their previous files and software, while they could not before the restore). The only problem is that their email is having issues. We use Outlook 2016 and Exchange Server 2013. I need to restore the original mailbox to the original Active Directory user. After I restored the original user profile/account, they now have a new mailbox that is empty. They need their original mailbox with their old emails in it and any archived emails for that mailbox. I have found numerous cmdlets to use in PowerShell, but I don’t want to cause any unintentional data loss.
I believe I have found the original mailbox using PowerShell to list any deleted/disabled mailboxes that haven’t been purged after 30 days, and the proper attributes are there (the original shows “Disabled” while the new and empty one has a blank attribute. However, I would love some assistance in this to ensure a successful restoration of the original Active Directory user and their Outlook 2016 mailbox. Can anyone out there please offer some tips or advice? Thank you so much in advance, and I know pictures would help, but I don’t want to post anything unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/delete-or-restore-mailboxes

Provided you have the appropriate Exchange permissions, you’ll be fine.